# trying to display field in json object, seeing field in console log, but nothing on the page Angular

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, interpolation

I have an object from my api, which I am interpolating in my template. All the fields display correctly, besides one. In the firestore database, this particular field is sometimes stored as a Timestamp, and sometimes as a string. When I try to display it, without any pipes, only the field itself, nothing appears, although I can see it when I console.log the object. I've tried changing the type in the interface to string, or any, or Timestamp, but nothing is displayed. I've also tried with and without an ngIf statement.

this is a part of the json object that shows the paybackSchedule.date field:
[image]

this is my object in the console showing the date fields (not all records contain this field)

[image]

function in ts file

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transactionsPayBackSchedules$ = this.pagination$.pipe(
      switchMap((pagination) => {
        return this.afs
          .collection<PaybackSchedule>('transactions', (ref) => {
            ref.where('paybackSchedule.status', 'in', ['PAID','IN_PROCESS'])
            let query: any = ref;
            if (pagination.after) {
              query = query
                .orderBy('paybackSchedule.paybackDate', 'desc')
                .startAfter(pagination.after.paybackDate)
                .limit(pagination.limit);
            }
            else if (pagination.before) {
              query = query
                .orderBy('paybackSchedule.paybackDate', 'desc')
                .endBefore(pagination.before.paybackDate)
                .limitToLast(pagination.limit);
            } else {
              query = query.orderBy('paybackSchedule.paybackDate', 'desc').limit(pagination.limit);
            }
            return query;
          }).valueChanges()
          .pipe(tap(console.log),tap(paybackScheduleArray => {
            const paybackSchedules = paybackScheduleArray;
            this.updateState({...STATE, paybackSchedules});
          }))

      })
    )
  }
```

template

```
<div *ngIf="transactionsPayBackSchedules$ | async as transactionsPaybackSchedules">

  <pre>{{transactionsPaybackSchedules  | json}}</pre>
  <div *ngFor="let paybackSchedule of transactionsPaybackSchedules">
    <div *ngIf="paybackSchedule.date"> {{paybackSchedule.date}}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

class file

```
export interface PaybackSchedule {
  amount: number;
  paybackDate: Timestamp;
  scheduleId: string;
  status: ScheduleStatus;
  payrollValidated: boolean;
  date: Timestamp;

//   constructor(args?) {
//     if (args) {
//       this.paybackDate = args.paybackSchedule.paybackDate;
//       this.date = args.paybackSchedule.date;
//
// }
// }
}
```

Comment: Did you use ? operator date?: Timestamp

Comment: I tried this in the interface: date?: Timestamp; it doesn't change the result @SanjayChoudhary